# Spring secure endpoint with only client credentials (Basic)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have oauth2 authorization server with one custom endpoint (log out specific user manually as admin)
I want this endpoint to be secured with rest client credentials (client id and secret as Basic encoded header value), similar to /oauth/check_token.

This endpoint can be called only from my resource server with specific scope.

1. I need to check if the client is authenticated.
2. I would like to be able to add @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('TEST_SCOPE')")on the controller`s method.

I could not find any docs or way to use the Spring`s mechanism for client authentication check.

**EDIT 1**

I use java config not an xml one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up with the following solution

**Authentication Manager**

```
public class ClientAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public HGClientAuthenticationManager(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    Assert.notNull(clientDetailsService, "Given clientDetailsService must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(passwordEncoder, "Given passwordEncoder must not be null!");
    this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    ClientDetails clientDetails = null;
    try {
        clientDetails = this.clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
    } catch (ClientRegistrationException e) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid client id or password");
    }
    if (!passwordEncoder.matches(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), clientDetails.getClientSecret())) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid client id or password");
    }
    return new OAuth2Authentication(
            new OAuth2Request(null, clientDetails.getClientId(), clientDetails.getAuthorities(), true,
                    clientDetails.getScope(), clientDetails.getResourceIds(), null, null, null),
            null);
}
}
```

**Filter declaration**

```
    private BasicAuthenticationFilter basicAuthenticationFilter() {
    ClientDetailsUserDetailsService clientDetailsUserDetailsService = new ClientDetailsUserDetailsService(
            this.clientDetailsService);
    clientDetailsUserDetailsService.setPasswordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
    return new BasicAuthenticationFilter(
            new ClientAuthenticationManager(this.clientDetailsService, this.passwordEncoder));
}
```

**Filter registration**

```
httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(this.basicAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

WARNING!!!
This will prevent any other types of authentication (oauth2, etc.). 
**ONLY** `Basic` authentication is accepted and **ONLY** for registered clients.

Answer (score 0):

`@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('TEST_SCOPE')")` On the controller method should be sufficiënt. If the client is not authenticated, no scope is available and the scope check will fail.

If you want, you can use the Spring Security expression `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` to check if a client is authenticated: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in

You could also configure the `HttpSecurity` instead of working with `@PreAuthorize`

Comment: That would work in `@EnableResourceServer`, but my question states that the controller in question is in the `@EnableAuthorizationServer`

Comment: client_credentials uses basic authentication to request an OAuth token. /oauth/check_token endpoint works with tokens, not the clientId & secret. If you want you can use the same mechanism as check_token token: load the authentication object based on the token. And check the authentication object for the correct scopes. You can find the code for check_token here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/CheckTokenEndpoint.java

Comment: Before the method `checkToken ` call, the client authentication is already checked. The method DOES NOT deal with the client authentication. The client credentials checks are done by using `BasicAuthenticationFilter` with `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService`.